# Create new dataframe based on relationships from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
car    wire    color
 x       1       red
 x       2       red 
 x       3       red
```

In this case each wire is colored 'red'. For the sake of this program it is safe to say that anything with the same color is connected. I want to use this information to make a NEW dataframe that would look like the following:

```
car    wire    connected
 x       1          2
 x       1          3
 x       2          3
```

Comment: You can use ```DataFrame.groupby``` to group the data by color and car. You can then generate all permutations of wires using ```itertools.permutations``` for each color in each car

Comment: @iamchoosinganame I'll have a look at the documentation, thank you!

Comment: How does this work for you? `from itertools import combinations; result = df.set_index('car').groupby('color')['wire'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(combinations(x, r=2), index=x.index))`

Comment: @cs95 this gives the error: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: Oops, my code runs on 0.25. Do list(combinations(..)) to convert the iterator to list, let me know what else happens.

Comment: This keeps telling me "list() takes no keyword arguments". I think I am missing something syntax wise

Comment: This works for me: `result = df.set_index('car').groupby('color')['wire'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(x, r=2)), index=x.index))`

Comment: Runs now, but get an index related error. Don't think this method will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have an inefficient, but effective solution. Now that I know car is important, I included in the answer. With the added complexity, this might not be the best solution because we have 3 nesting for loops which will negatively impact performance. Also negatively impacting performance is appending every time we see a new row. Long story short: this code will work but slooooooowly.

```
from itertools import permutations
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['wire','connected','car']) # Initialize result
# Iterate through car options
for car in df['car'].unique():
    tdf = df[df['car']==car]
    # Iterate through color options
    for color in tdf['color'].unique():
        wires = list(tdf[tdf['color']==color]['wire']) # Get a list of wires

        # Iterate thru all possible combinations of connected wires when shoosing 2 wires
        for w in permutations(wires,2):

            # Append that possible combination to the dataframe
            result = result.append(
                pd.DataFrame({
                    'wire':w[0],
                    'connected':w[1],
                    'car':car
                })
            )

            # Optional: If you need the revers too. For example if 1 -> 2 also needs 2 -> 1 in the result
            result = result.append(
                pd.DataFrame({
                    'wire':w[1],
                    'connected':w[0],
                    'car':car
                })
            )
```

Comment: In this case "car" is important because it gives the wires uniqueness. "car x" could have wires 1,2,3,4,etc. "car y" could also have the same wires. They aren't the same wires though, if that makes sense.